# C++ switching to passing arguments by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I made a rather large program that I didn't expect to grow so much so I didn't bother to pass argument for functions by reference, so they are mostly passed by value, and want to change this (for performance reasons) to passing by reference in all but a handful of functions. There are more than 1000 of them. What way would you suggest I do this?(manual is out of the question)
I could make a small patcher that would place '&' around my code, but is there a way to maybe tell the compiler to pass them by reference every time, by default? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: No, there is no such option.

Comment: Sorry , prepare and starch your fingers to retype it, and be careful because it will be an untactful change.

Comment: The choice between references and copies should not have anything to do with performance. It's a change in semantics and behaviour! Unless you mean const references, of course.

Comment: performance reasons? Have you actually measured the cost of copying an argument? if it's significant anywhere it will only be so in a handful of functions. Counter-intuitively, copies of large objects can actually be extremely fast. Complex objects that involve a lot of memory allocation are worth looking at. Almost nothing else is.

Comment: @RichardHodges Now that you say it this way, I guess I don't really have to change a lot - I should only focus on some arrays and make move constructors for most objects while leaving basic types the way they are already.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to fix it by hand, no compiler will do it for you. When changing ie. `void foo(std::string)` to `void foo(std::string& str)`, you have to make decision if thats correct - ie. if `foo` maybe modifies `str`, you dont want to change your program behaviour. Actually it will be safier if you choose to move to const& - thats: `void foo(const std::string& str)`.

You might also consider at some places to use move semantics instead of converting to references. You would have to modify classes/structures by adding move constructors and assignment operators. As you can see in below link, move semantics are available in VS2012.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665(v=vs.110).aspx

But it will help you only in specific cases, when you call `foo` with temporary or argument that is no longer localy needed.

Probably you dont need to fix all your code, but only the most frequently called functions. So I would suggest to profile your code first.

Comment: Thanks, move constructors are a great technology, they save a lot of memory and time, also are very easy to implement.